# parse frame and files occupies more memory

Tags: ios, image, file-transfer

In my app i want store images in cloud( for that im using parse.com). My problem is if I add parse framework(as instructed by parse.com/apps/quickstart)it occupies 20mb of memory. Is there any way to reduce the memory of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASIHTTPrequest

see below link-
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: this class will help you to upload and download images to/from server

Comment: In my app i want store images in cloud( for that im using parse.com). My problem is if I add parse framework(as instructed by https://parse.com/apps/quickstart)it occupies 20mb of memory. Is there any way to reduce the memory of my app?